# Solving function which results singularity during discrete summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, summation-method, ramanujan-summation

I am sorry if the following query is too basic or technically incorrect. Actually I am quite away from mathematics so I could not figure out how to solve this.

I have the following function.

$$f(\Theta,\Phi) = \int_0^\pi d\phi \int_0^\pi d\theta \frac{sin\theta}{\sqrt{1-\{\cos\Theta \cos \theta +\sin\Theta \sin\theta\cos(\Phi-\phi)\}^2}} $$

for $\Theta = \Phi = 0$
$$f(0,0) = \int_0^\pi d\phi \int_0^\pi d\theta \frac{sin\theta}{\sqrt{1-\{\cos0 \cos \theta +\sin0 \sin\theta\cos(0-\phi)\}^2}}$$

$\implies$ $$f(0,0) = \int_0^\pi d\phi \int_0^\pi d\theta \frac{sin\theta}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2 \theta}} $$
$\implies$
 $$f(0,0) = \int_0^\pi d\phi \int_0^\pi d\theta \frac{sin\theta}{\sin\theta} $$

$\implies$
$$f(0,0) = \pi^2$$

But if I want to calculate using discrete summation then,
firstly I take 
$$\Delta i = \Delta j = \frac{\pi}{180}$$
and $$i = j = (0,1,2...,180)$$
$$\theta_i = \phi_i = \frac{i}{180}\pi$$
$$f(0,0) = \Delta i \Delta j \sum_{i=1}^{180}\sum_{j=1}^{180}\frac{sin\theta_i}{\sqrt{1-\{\cos0 \cos \theta_i +\sin0 \sin\theta_i\cos(0-\phi_j)\}^2}}$$
But at when I calculate it using Matlab, then at  $i =j= 1$ above equation results to $\inf$ or singularity.

I just want to calculate it discretely. Can someone help me with some methods which I can follow to calculate this discretely?

Thanks in advance

Comment: At the least we must avoid using $i=180$, since the program may be upset about being asked to divide by $0$. The singularity at $\pi$ turns out to be harmless, but the program does not know that.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks for the comment. $i=180$ can be avoided but the problem exists with $i=0$.

Comment: You can avoid that too. Just sum over "safe" points. There are many more sophisticated techniques for dealing with singularities, but ad-hoc methods ae probably fine here.

Comment: Thanks again for the comment @AndréNicolas . Can you please name a few methods? I would like to read them since the application of this formulation has other implications so I can not simply calculate on the safe points.